# Scaling and centering a web page to fit any device/window dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I have a web app (Cordova) that I've designed to a specific width and height. I want the document body to scale down to fit no matter what device (phone, tablet, browser) i put it on. If device is bigger than my designed dimensions, the document body should not scale up but instead center itself in the window. I've got the scale calculations down ok i think, but I can't seem to get the body and contents to center both vertically and horizontally.

Here is a demo (small 300x400 dimensions for demo):

http://jsfiddle.net/D2e4W/

Resize the Result window to see it rescale.  I've got it working vertically (well Chrome only), but shrinking horizontally causes it to shift right.  I'm open to totally different methods than what i've got here.

Relevent code:

```
<body>
    <div id='div1'></div>
</body>

<script>
var max_width  = 300;
var max_height = 400;
window.addEventListener('resize', on_window_resize);
on_window_resize();

function on_window_resize()
{
    //if either window dimension is less than max, scale body to fit
    var h_scale = window.innerHeight / max_height;  
    var w_scale = window.innerWidth / max_width;        
    var page_scale = 1;
    if (h_scale < 1 || w_scale < 1) 
    {
        page_scale = (h_scale < w_scale) ? h_scale : w_scale;
    }   

    //display scale string    
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
    div1.innerHTML = "scale: " +  page_scale.toFixed(2);


    //scale body using webkit transforms
    var scale_str = "scale(" + page_scale + ")";

    document.body.style.webkitTransform = scale_str;
    document.body.style.transform       = scale_str;    
    //document.body.style.webkitTransformOrigin = "0 0";
    //document.body.style.transformOrigin = "0 0";

    //div1.style.webkitTransform = scale_str;
    //div1.style.transform       = scale_str;   
    //div1.style.webkitTransformOrigin = "0 0";
    //div1.style.transformOrigin = "0 0";

}
</script>

<style>
body 
{
    overflow:hidden;    
    background-color: #444444;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;    
}

#div1
{
    overflow = 'hidden';
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #dd4444;
    font-size: 60px;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The more appropriate way to do this would be in CSS with media queries which adjust the styles based on the size of the window/view:

For example your 300x400 box:

```
body 
{
    overflow:hidden;    
    background-color: #444444;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;    
}

#div1
{
    overflow = 'hidden';
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #dd4444;
    font-size: 60px;

    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

@media all and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:1000px) {
  #div1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44aAy/2/

When the window is a minimum of 300 pixels wide but no larger then 1000 pixels the box will change size and turn green. Make the box smaller again and it is red.

There are frameworks, such as Twitter Bootstrap, Skeleton and others with this built in for responsive web design.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the width being set the  is forcing it to appear to the right.